# Caching the assetss that include Css and js files in grails application

Tags: css, caching, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.2

currently the project i am working on is using cache:1.1.1 plugin with grails 2.2.4. but for some reason its not working and in browser under the network tab i get status 200 instead of 304 every time i reload the page.
I have tried different plugin versions but in vain.
i don't want any special functions to be cached. I just need my assets, so that the loading time speeds up.

```
compile ":cache:1.1.1",
```

I have read about the ehcache somewhere but don't know whether it'll work or not.

Comment: Are you running your application deployed as a war, or is this happening when you use `run-app`? I ask because I think caching isn't enabled in development mode.

Comment: currently doing run-app but let me try to deploy this app (Y)

Comment: deploying the app doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The cache plugin doesn't have anything to do with assets - for that you should look at the [asset-pipeline](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) plugin and its addon plugins.

The [cache](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) plugin caches method call results (typically service methods) and GSP page fragments, and should be used when the method will return the same result given the same inputs (or the GSP section will generate the same output) and is time-consuming or resource-intensive to compute, so caching those values and not recomputing the values every time can save a lot of server load. It doesn't do anything by default; you need to add annotations to methods that should be cached, and wrap the sections of GSPs that should be cached in a taglib call. See [the documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache/) for more info.

Comment: asset-pipeline does the compile=false but doesnt store the asset fr longer run i assume

Comment: It doesn't cache when running locally with `run-app` but if you deploy a WAR file you'll see that it definitely does add resource caching. Is the asset-pipeline plugin installed?

Comment: yeah its installed